# Installing a water softener - Brine tank overflow w/o drain nearby

Tags: water-softener

My old water softener isn't working anymore and so I wanted to replace it myself. The kind I have currently is one where the salt tank and the other tank are separate and the kind I am looking to get is an all in one unit (http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-40-000-Grain-Water-Softener-GXSH40V/203219780)

Overall the install seems pretty easy since the plumbing is already there but there is a difference in my current setup and the new one, specifically the new one has a brine tank overflow that you are supposed to run a hose to a drain and it cannot go uphill. This is separate from the Valve Drain hose which also needs to be run to a drain and my current system has one of these.  The value drain can run uphill and whoever installed my current system has it running into my attic where it drains. The unit is in my garage and so there is no drain in the floor and it would be quite costly to install one.

Since I cannot run the brine hose uphill and there is not a drain in my floor are there any good options other than get a different unit that isn't an all in one?

Comment: Your best bet is probably a condensate pump which will collect and pump the brine uphill. It's an educated guess, but I don't see why a good one wouldn't keep up with the softener.